# Grouping records based on condition through linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have data in below mentioned format and I need to create group of records where number is equal to linkednumber through C# linq or lambda expression and loop through them to further process them. I can create groups based on matching fields. But in this case field names are different, but values are same. Not sure how to group two different fields with mactching values.

```
   '''
        <Fields>
           <field name="number" value="1111"/>
           <field name="linkednumber" value="999" />
        </Fields>
        <Fields>
           <field name="number" value="999>
           <field name="linkednumber" value="1111>
        </Fields>
        <Fields>
            <field name="number" value="222">
            <field name="linkednumber" value="888/>
       </Fields>
       <Fields>
           <field name="number" value="888>
           <field name="linkednumber" value="222>
       </Fields>
       <Fields>
          <field name="number" value="333">
          <field name="linkednumber" value="777">
       </Fields>
     <Fields>
        <field name="number" value="777">
        <field name="linkednumber" value="333">
    </Fields>
    '''
```

Here are the reference classes -

```
    public class Fields
    {
        public FieldsField[] Field { get; set; }
       
    }

    
    public class FieldsField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You already have classes that represent this data and want to show us?

Comment: In your sample number and linkednumber are never equal for one field. Or do you want all numbers and there linkednumbers that mach in the whole dataset?

Comment: @Ralf  classes are like -  public class Fields
    {
        public FieldsField[] Field { get; set; }
       
    }

    
    public class FieldsField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You can update the question with additional info.

Comment: @jeb yes I want all records in group where number of a record matches linkednumber of other records. In the given example, there should be 3 group of records.

Comment: Does the real data have some kind of Name or Id ? it is pretty hard to identify a found entity. Let's say for number 1111 linkednumber 1111 was found. What do you want to have back ? The Field ?

Comment: Yes! The field. I need both field entity in each match. I need to iterate through  each such match.

Comment: You should add the desired answer to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I skipped the xml parsing since you already seem to have it.
I am assuming that each Number has only one LinkedNumber. If that's not the case you would need a List of Matches instead. So I post both. The list version is commented.

```
public class MatchingFields
{
    public Fields Start { get; set; }
    public Fields Match { get; set; }
   // public List<Fields> Match { get; set; } = new List<Fields>();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var entries = LoadFields();

    List<MatchingFields> infoList = new();

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        var number = entry.Field.First(f => f.Name == "number").Value;
        // Find other fields where linkednumber is equal to our current number
        var matchingFields = entries
            .Where(e => e.Field.Any(f => f.Name == "linkednumber" && f.Value == number))
            .ToList();

        var match = new MatchingFields();
        match.Start = entry;
        match.Match = matchingFields.First();
        
        //foreach (var matchingField in matchingFields)
        //{
        //    match.Match.Add(matchingField);
        //}

        infoList.Add(match);
    }
}
```

Here is my sample data based on your model:

```
private static Fields[] LoadFields()
{
    // Simulated data for demonstration
    return new Fields[]
    {
        new Fields
        {
            Field = new FieldsField[]
            {
                new FieldsField { Name = "number", Value = "1111" },
                new FieldsField { Name = "linkednumber", Value = "999" }
            }
        },
        new Fields
        {
            Field = new FieldsField[]
            {
                new FieldsField { Name = "number", Value = "999" },
                new FieldsField { Name = "linkednumber", Value = "1111" }
            }
        },
        new Fields
        {
            Field = new FieldsField[]
            {
                new FieldsField { Name = "number", Value = "222" },
                new FieldsField { Name = "linkednumber", Value = "888" }
            }
        },
        new Fields
        {
            Field = new FieldsField[]
            {
                new FieldsField { Name = "number", Value = "888" },
                new FieldsField { Name = "linkednumber", Value = "222" }
            }
        },
        new Fields
        {
            Field = new FieldsField[]
            {
                new FieldsField { Name = "number", Value = "333" },
                new FieldsField { Name = "linkednumber", Value = "777" }
            }
        },
        new Fields
        {
            Field = new FieldsField[]
            {
                new FieldsField { Name = "number", Value = "777" },
                new FieldsField { Name = "linkednumber", Value = "333" }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also achieved desired results.